# Outlook HTML newsletter: text over transparent image over image

Tags: html, css, outlook, newsletter, vml

I'm trying to create a newsletter who works in Outlook.

It should look like (and it does in browsers or good email clients):
[image]

But it looks like in Outlook 2019:
[image]

Two issues:

1. The transparent background image is just white and covers the text and the image.
2. The second transparent background image is ignored completely.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <style>
      /* Reset */
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      a,
      a:focus,
      a:hover {
        color: inherit;
        outline: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      /* General */
      body {
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Roboto', 'Segeo UI', Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
      }

      a {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: underline;
      }

      .spacer-5 {
        height: 5px;
      }

      .spacer-10 {
        height: 10px;
      }

      /* Section */
      .heading {
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
        max-width: 1160px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
      }

      .content {
        color: #000000;
        font-weight: 600;
        max-width: 1160px;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
      }

      .content a {
        color: #000000;
      }
    </style>
    <title>Newsletter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td width="1200">
          <table class="section" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
              <td background="https://i.ibb.co/WDCt928/img-1.png" bgcolor="#dddddd" valign="top" style="background-size:cover;">
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:1200px;">
                  <v:fill type="tile" size="100%,100%" src="https://i.ibb.co/WDCt928/img-1.png" color="#dddddd" />
                  <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
                <![endif]-->
                <div>
                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="spacer-10" colspan="2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td background="https://i.ibb.co/TYkzN4c/transparent.png" class="heading" valign="top">
                        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="mso-width-percent:1000;">
                          <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.ibb.co/TYkzN4c/transparent.png"/>
                          <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
                        <![endif]-->
                        <div>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                        </div>
                        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                          </v:textbox>
                        </v:rect>
                        <![endif]-->
                      </td>
                      <td width="40"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="spacer-5" colspan="2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td background="https://i.ibb.co/TYkzN4c/transparent.png" class="content">
                        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="mso-width-percent:1000;">
                          <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.ibb.co/TYkzN4c/transparent.png"/>
                          <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
                        <![endif]-->
                        <div>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                        </div>
                        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                          </v:textbox>
                        </v:rect>
                        <![endif]-->
                      </td>
                      <td width="40"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="spacer-10" colspan="2"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                  </v:textbox>
                </v:rect>
                <![endif]-->
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0hb6Lqf4/

Comment: Try to use transparent background on `table` rather then `td`, just like you use above colored bg image

Comment: And how about using `background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);` instead of a semi-transparent white image?

Comment: @ArturCapraro Outlook does not support this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting this as a `style` attribute on the `TD`?
Outlook might strip the background image from TD itself or doesn't recognise this as a valid attribute, where a `style=""` could do the trick.

This is what I've done in my own newsletter to fix it.
So in your case:

From: 
`<td background="https://i.ibb.co/TYkzN4c/transparent.png" class="content">`

to: 
`<td style="background: url('https://i.ibb.co/TYkzN4c/transparent.png');" class="content">`

Also keep in mind that if you domain is not `ibb.co`, mail clients tend to hide images by default and "Allow" the user to download external images.

Answer (score 0):

i have used one node npm package haml.io and its worked like charm